# Wrong highlighting and indentation of Javascript micro templates in Vim

Tags: javascript, html, vim, syntax-highlighting, indentation

I use Javascript [micro templates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) inside html and html.erb files in a Rails application. Unfortunately all html tags inside the `script` tag (with `type="test/html"` are not correctly highlighted, nor do I get a correct indentation (after going to the next line I always end up at the first position).

Is there simple way to fix that? Which of those Vim plugins I use in my [.vimrc (link to Gist)](https://gist.github.com/4078697) is responsible for highlighting and indentation of html in html and html.erb files (maybe I can fix it there)?

Comment: From the code it seems that the vim-javascript plugin is responsible for that. I opened a bug report there: https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/issues/63